# Mocha complains that cb is not a function when running yeoman generator tests

Tags: mocha.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I built a yeoman generator that grabs data from a rest api and populates html, css, and js files in an app dir with those files. I am trying to learn how to build the respective mocha test but keep running into an error on my file exist test.

I pass the "does the generator load" test, but when i try the "do files exist" test, I get an error at the console that:

```
1)creates files creates expected files:
Uncaught TypeError: cb is not a function
at null.<anonymous> (node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:400:5)
at Queue.<anonymous> (node_modules/grouped-queue/lib/queue.js:68:12)
```

My test is as follows

```
/*global describe, beforeEach, it*/
'use strict';

var path    = require('path');
var helpers = require('yeoman-generator').test;

describe("creates files", function(){
    beforeEach(function (done){
        helpers.testDirectory(path.join(__dirname, 'temp'), function(err){
            if(err){
                return done(err);
            }

            this.app = helpers.createGenerator('snow:app',['../../app']);

            done();
        }.bind(this));
    });

    it("creates expected files", function(done){
        helpers.mockPrompt(this.app,{
            hostname : "empasiegel1",
            username : "password",
            password : "password",
            solution : "testSnow"
        });

        this.app.run({}, function() {
            helpers.assertFile('package.json');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Could it have soemthing to do with the asynchronous nature of the rest calls?

Comment: my project is on git: https://github.com/stegel/generator-snow

Comment: You should start by reading our testing documentation http://yeoman.io/authoring/testing.html